# I am getting SAXParseException: Invalid content type was found ... for incoming xml response message but it passes when tested explicitly

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am getting `SAXParseException: Invalid content type was found` for incoming xml response message, but when I explicitly try to parse xml against xsd it passes successfully. Please can anyone advise why the exception is occurring when my application is reading from MQ. My application uses MDB with JMS.

Is it like my program is not reading complete xml response message due to some filter on length?

Answer (score 0):

If it's saying invalid content type for an incoming XML response, I'm going to assume your application is requesting this XML, and the server is sending a Content-Type header that SAX isn't liking.

Make sure the server is actually indicating the content type is xml not plaintext or something else.